# fuzzy match based on a list of patterns in R

Tags: r, string, fuzzy-comparison

I need to generate a dummy variable based on a list of patterns.

```
df <- data.frame(
  med = c("sivastatin", "sisvatatin", "rusvastatin", "yes", "no", "don't remember", "true", "false", "omega 3", "atorvastatin", "no")
)
```

I need to create a second dummy variable that indicates if the patient used or not any med. I tried this:

```
yes <- c("yes", "vastatin", "true", "don't remember")

nao <- c("no", "false") 

df$med_cat <- ifelse(agrepl(yes, df$med, ignore.case = TRUE), 1, 
                  ifelse(agrepl(no, df$med, ignore.case = TRUE), 0, NA))
```

But I'm getting an error saying that only the first element is being used

*argument 'pattern' length > 1 and only the first element is going to used Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, med_cat, value = logical(0)) : replacement has 0 rows, data has 8381*

can someone help me with this?

SOLUTION:

```
df$med_cat <- ifelse(apply(sapply(yes, agrepl, df$med_cholstand, .1), 1, any), 1,
                             ifelse(apply(sapply(no, agrepl, df$med_cholstand, .1), 1, any), 0, NA))
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Do you need `+(grepl(paste0("\\b(", paste(yes, collapse="|"), ")\\b"), df$med))`

Comment: thanks @akrun, but it's still not solvel all the problem. It's still missing when it's not the exactly patter like "sivastatin", "sisvatatin" :(

Comment: if there are some changes in the spelling, you can use `fuzzyjoin`

Comment: You could use the inversion ie `+!grepl(sprintf("\\b(%s)\\b", paste0(no, collapse="|")), df$med)`

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to the problem:

```
df$med_cat <- ifelse(apply(sapply(yes, agrepl, df$med_cholstand, .1), 1, any), 1,
                             ifelse(apply(sapply(no, agrepl, df$med_cholstand, .1), 1, any), 0, NA))
```